# How to fetch array from Class Method

Tags: php

I am trying to get the name of a user in my DB using a method but I am getting a `Notice`. I previously got help with this but that was for two values and not one. The original columns were `first_name` and `last_name` I changed first name to name and dropped the last name column. So now I just want to get the name.

I am getting this notice `Notice: Array to string conversion in`. Essentially I just want to change this line to get only one column(`name`).

```
return $query_result->fetch_assoc() ?? ['first_name' => '[no', 'last_name' => 'name]'];
```

But here is the whole method:

```
public function getFirstAndLastName() {

    $query = $this->con->prepare("SELECT name FROM users WHERE username = ?");
    $query->bind_param("s", $this->user['username']);
    $query->execute();
    $query_result = $query->get_result();

    //return $query_result->fetch_assoc() ?? ['name'];
    return $query_result->fetch_assoc() ?? ['first_name' => '[no', 'last_name' => 'name]'];
}
```

The commented line is how I tried to get the name but it didn't work.

These are the lines I am getting the error on:

```
echo "<h4>You and <a href='$user_to'>" . $user_to_obj->getFirstAndLastName() . "</a></h4><hr><br>";
```

and this one

```
". $user_found_obj->getFirstAndLastName() ."<br/>".
```

Comment: `return $query_result->fetch_assoc()['name']`

Comment: Would you like to put that as an answer ? It works.

Comment: There must be a duplicate somewhere I just cannot find it :)